# subscriber callback unable to access class member

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not really sure if this is a ROS problem or a C++ problem, but it's blowing my mind.

- I have a class with a vector of structs in it.
- I construct some structs and `push_back` them into the vector
- In the constructor of the struct, I create a subscriber
- The callback of this subscriber is a member function of the struct.
- The subscriber successfully gets called when a message is published, but the callback doesn't have valid member data.

My question is: what is going on here? I know a few quick ways to solve the problem, but they're kind of cheating, and anyway, I want to understand. I'm thinking it's either that I'm unaware of some threading issue ros is doing behind the scenes, or the `this` pointer isn't getting correctly to the subscriber. But I've tried everything I could think to do.

Here's a minimal example like what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Bool.h>

struct S{
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber subscriber;
    unsigned int _number;

    S(std::string topic_name, unsigned int number){
        _number = number;
        ROS_INFO("the number is %i",_number);   //prints out as 5
        subscriber = n.subscribe<std_msgs::Bool>(topic_name, 1, &S::S_cb, this);
    }
    void S_cb(const std_msgs::Bool::ConstPtr &msg){
        ROS_INFO("performing foo on %i", _number);   //prints out as 0 - why???
        //foo(_number, msg->data);
    }
};

class TestNode{
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  std::vector<S> s_array;

public:
  TestNode(std::string name){
    s_array.push_back(S("test_topic",5));
  }
  ~TestNode(){ }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");

  TestNode tn(ros::this_node::getName());
  
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85801/subscriber-callback-unable-to-access-class-member/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-01**:
Does this compile? Shouldn't S need a S() constructor to be put into a vector?

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-10-01**:
I didn't compile the above test case (probably should have...), but the real code it's based on compiles fine.  Anyway, according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), this way to initialize a vector creates a vector of 0 S elements, so no Ss are constructed until push_back happens

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-01**:
Doesn't matter. You can still call resize(n) that will default construct n elements. My guess is this should give a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a guess, someone that knows the internals can determine this more clearly: This has to do with the fact that a vector inserts by copying values. Before you push_back a temporary is created, which the subscriber is initialized with (including this pointer). This is copied into the vector - the resulting object in the vector has a different this pointer, but the subscriber is copied by value - it can't know the new this pointer. Then the temporary is destroyed and you get random memory when in the callback.

Proper fix for this: Make a copy-constructor + maybe assignment operator that re-initializes the subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-10-01**:
This makes perfect sense, and using a copy-constructor fixes the problem. I should have read [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) more carefully.